# Add one column to another column in next row mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query as below:

```
SELECT a.name, ifnull(d.y,0) as y, a.color
                FROM (
                    SELECT 'Jan' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Feb' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Mar' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Apr' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Apr' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'May' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Jun' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Jul' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Aug' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Sep' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Oct' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Nov' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color UNION
                    SELECT 'Dec' name, 0 y, '#6F9BD2' color

                ) AS a LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT order_date, sum(total_value) AS y
                    FROM saleorder where year(order_date) =".$yearSelect." group by month(order_date)) as d ON a.name = DATE_FORMAT(d.order_date, '%b')
```

The result of the above said query is [image]

The above mentioned mysql query generate all months for a specified year and calculate the total sale for the particular month.  Now my issue is, the value of 'y' column should be calculated by adding the value in the following scenario:

```
value of y in  jan -> jan
value of y in  feb -> value of y in jan+ value of y in feb
value of y in  march -> value of y in jan+value of y in feb+ value of y in march
.
.
.
december -> jan+feb+march+april+may+jun+jul+aug+sep+oct+nov+december
```

How to write the mysql query to get the value in this pattern in mysql

Comment: could you explain it more clearer

Comment: Why can't you handle that at server side scripting language? Just maintain a variable for value `y` and sum up in the loop.